# Docker container for on-demand deployment of other Docker containers

Tags: deployment, docker, images, containers

I have read the "Getting Started" introduction on Docker's website, but I still have one question I could not find an answer to:

Is it possible to set up a Docker container which can create other containers (real-time) ? For instance, can I create a container called "ContainerDeployer" which can 
1. Download existing containers from Docker's official, public Docker Hub repository and deploy them?
2. Create a new image based on user input and then run a container from the newly created image?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's sort of the idea behind PAAS, a system that allows automated builds to be deployed (or just standard containers), you're really simplifying the process though.

Comment: Sounds a bit like this: https://blog.docker.com/2013/09/docker-can-now-run-within-docker/

Comment: Sure, that's possible. Not sure why you don't want to use Docker's API directly but you can also run your ContainerDeployer in a container which has the Docker socket bind mounted to it.